# In depth detail of data being produced to newrelic

Tags: newrelic

We went through https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/data-apis/manage-data/manage-data-coming-new-relic/

It just shows around 7 sources of data being ingested to newrelic.

We want to know more details exactly what type of data from which all apps are being ingested so that we can reduce the amount.

We even tried to run following query based on https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/new-relic-solutions/observability-maturity/operational-efficiency/data-governance-baseline-ingest-guide/#prereqs

```
 SELECT * FROM NrConsumption LIMIT 5
```

It gave only two rows in result.

Comment: I believe you want to add a time window to that query such as `SINCE 30 days ago` - the default time window is only 60 minutes if no time is defined within a query.

Comment: query is showing more result after following ur suggestion. But query is also not giving much more detail. it is just showing that TracingBytes are largest contributor. I want to know how can i reduce it.

Answer (score 1):

As per the question - you are asking if you can see all app names that are contributing to data ingest. And as there is a mention of ‘appNames’ I am assuming you are referring to APM data ingest.

The steps to get there is:
Data Management Hub
Click on APM Events in legend -> Click on the area for APM (Or directly click on APM area in the chart)
Pick the query from the modal (Usually looks something like below)

```
SELECT bytecountestimate()/10e8 FROM `Transaction`, `TransactionError` FACET appName LIMIT 15 SINCE 1684442429581 UNTIL 1684528829581
```

Note that the modal only shows Top 15 results for last 24 hours. But the query from the modal can be modified to show data ingest details for longer time window too by updating the SINCE and UNTIL clauses to `SINCE 30 DAYS AGO UNTIL TODAY`

Comment: Thanks. your query does give the data for each app. Is it possible to drill down more per app wise data so that we can reduce data .
I had tried to reduce max_samples_stored from 2000 to 1000. i was hoping data ingestion will decrease by 50 % , but it is almost same . any idea why?